# How to keep IP given from DHCP server when changing DHCP client from udhcpc to systemd-networkd

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, dhcp, udhcpc

I have a device I want to upgrade its filesystem and packages.
What's installed now is some kind of [buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) with [busybox](https://www.busybox.net/). Its DHCP client is `udhcpc` and I run it like this `/sbin/udhcpc -R -b -p /var/run/udhcpc.eth0.pid -i eth0` in order to gain IP for `eth0`.

I'm upgrading the filesystem and packages to be `Ubuntu 18.04` based instead of `buildroot`.
As part of it, the new DHCP client is `systemd-networkd`.

The IP given with `udhcpc` before the FS upgrade is different from the IP given after with `systemd-networkd`.
This is for the same interface with the same mac.

Is there a way somehow to keep the old IP?

Comment: The usual method is to configure the DHCP Server always to issue the same IP address for the given MAC

Comment: @roaima so you're saying that's an issue with the DHCP server only?

Comment: No I didn't say that. I said that the usual way to guarantee a particular IP address in a DHCP environment was to configure the DHCP Server

Comment: The thing is, when I move back to `udhcpc` from `systemd-networkd` it gets back to the old `DHCP IP`

Comment: Yes. It asks for the same one it had last time. But there's no guarantee the DHCP Server will give it out.

Comment: Also maybe the new dhcp client uses (IPv4) DUID while the older didn't: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4361

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [systemd-networkd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html):

> [`[DHCPv4] Section Options`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#%5BDHCPv4%5D%20Section%20Options)

> [...]

> [`ClientIdentifier=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#ClientIdentifier=)
>
> The DHCPv4 client identifier to use. Takes one of `mac`, `duid` or
> `duid-only`. **If set to `mac`, the MAC address of the link is used.** If set
> to `duid`, an [RFC4361](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4361)-compliant Client ID, which is the combination of
> IAID and DUID (see below), is used. If set to `duid-only`, only DUID is
> used, this may not be RFC compliant, but some setups may require to
> use this. **Defaults to `duid`**.

- If you want to revert to the behavior obtained by the previous installation and it didn't use any DUID, then use this parameter:

  ```
  ClientIdentifier=mac
  ```
- If the older installation was using a DUID and possibly an interface specific IAID, these values will also have to be retrieved from it. They should then be used in, or affect various other parameters described in the documentation

  ```
  ClientIdentifier=
  DUIDType=
  DUIDRawData=
  IAID=
  ... ?
  ```

Hopefully you are in the former case.

Now, as it's about a *server* so some stability should be achievable, as @[roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100397/roaima) wrote in a comment, the proper way to keep the same IP address in a simple network setup is probably to change settings on the DHCP server to leave no choice on the DHCP client side.

Comment: Looks like the former case doesn't help :( .
Do you know why `duid` is the default? why is is better than `mac`?
And, how these values can be retrieved ?
Thanks

Comment: Details on the "why" are in the RFC and the RFCs it links to, sorry. For the default, ask the developpers. About your case, if you think the former installation was using a duid it's time to check its configuration. The word duid doesn't appear in its man page so I don't think there was any duid in use before. You should describe (by editing your question) what you tried that didn't work in case it helps resolve your case

Comment: I checked again. Actually using `ClientIdentifier=mac` just doesn't work. I still see in the dhcp request client identifier of `Enterprise-number: Tom Gundersen (systemd)`.
I have `systemd` version 237 of `ubuntu 18.04`. This should solve it because in the old filesystem, the client identifier is `mac`. :/

Comment: ok, I've moved `ClientIdentifier=mac` to be under `[DHCP] section and it worked! Thanks!